# Getting package com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier does not exist, while try to get google advertising id

Tags: java, android, identifier, google-advertising-id

I am fetching Google advertising id in my application, I have updated my android studio and android SDK.

```
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 27
Current gradle version is : 3.1.3
Google services is : 3.0.0
Google Play Services Version : 11.8.0
android Support Libraries Version : 27.1.1
```

While fetching GAID, I am getting following error

> error: package com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier does not exist

Not able to find **AdvertisingIdClient** class.

I am bit stuck here, Please help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The solution here worked for me
https://www.solutionfactory.in/posts/error-package-com-google-android-gms-ads-solved

adding this to my gradle build file particularly solved my problem.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

Seems that google has moved it to ads play services!

You have to add `implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1` to  your dependencies